# View into IndicatorViewPager React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, viewpagerindicator

I'm trying to create IndicatorViewPager with three parts. 
the problem that I can't see the content of each page. Below my code.

```
export default class Reservations extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <IndicatorViewPager
                           style={{flex:1, paddingTop:20, backgroundColor:'white'}}
                indicator={this._renderTitleIndicator()}
            >
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'cadetblue'}}>
                    <Text>page one</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'cornflowerblue'}}>
                    <Text>page two</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'#1AA094'}}>
                    <Text>page three</Text>
                </View>
            </IndicatorViewPager>
        </View>
    );
}

_renderTitleIndicator() {
    return <PagerTitleIndicator titles={['one', 'two', 'three']} />;
}
```

I have the title for each part but the content is hidden. Thank you for your help.